# What is a moment for a joint distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am currently self-learning probability theory using measure theory. Moments are defined as $\int X^k \ d P$, where $X$ is a stochastic variable and $P$ is the corresponding probability measure. If this has a density, then it becomes $\int x^k \circ X \ d P = \int x^k \ d X(P) = \int x^k f(x) \ dx$, if the density is $f$ with respect to Lebesgue measure.

But what is the analogue of all of this when it comes to the random variable $Y = (X_1,X_2)$? What are the moments of $Y$?

Comment: Define the random variable $Y := X_1X_2$. Its moments are given by

$$M_Y(t) = E[e^{tY}]$$

i think?

Comment: Classmate/Cross post? http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188389/what-is-the-moment-of-a-joint-random-variable